# Randomizing source files for audio application

Tags: ios, objective-c

So here is what I need to figure out. I have a folder of 6 wav files in a folder which I need to pull from every time I press a button for them to be played. What would be the most straightforward way of going about this? The `URLForResource` needs to be randomized equally between CLIP_1 .. CLIP_6

```
    NSURL *inputFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CLIP_1" withExtension:@"wav"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`arc4random_uniform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html) to generate random number to decide which clip should be used

```
int num = arc4random_uniform(6) + 1; // random number from 1 to 6
NSString *clipname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CLIP_%d", num];
NSURL *inputFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:clipname  withExtension:@"wav"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a random number between `0` and `N` with `arc4random_uniform(N)`.

You can construction a string containing a number with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CLIP_%d", number];`

If you use both of these techniques, what you are trying to do should be simple.